# Android app: Place content data in resources or use classes?

Tags: android, arrays

I am creating my first android app and in it I have a ViewPager which contains 3 different lists. The user can therefore swipe between 3 lists. The lists themselves are populated by using an arrayAdapter and currently my arrays are defined in strings.xml like this:

```
<string-array name="first_array">
    <item>item1</item>
    <item>item2</item>
    <item>item3</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="second_array">
...
```

I am using FragmentStatePagerAdapter to generate different 'pages' (each carrying a unique list) and this is achieved by:

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
  Fragment fragment = new MyListFragment();
  Bundle args = new Bundle();
  int argValue=0;
  switch(i) {
    case 0: argValue = R.array.first_array; break;
    case 1: argValue = R.array.second_array; break;
    case 2: argValue = R.array.third_array; break;
  }
  args.putInt(MyListFragment.ARG_KEY, argValue);
  fragment.setArguments(args);
  return fragment;
}

@Override
public int getCount() { return 3; }
```

However, this is not nice since if I ever decide to remove/add/edit the name of a list, I will have to come back here and reflect the changes here, introducing strong coupling.

So I am thinking of creating a java class which holds the arrays instead of in res/strings.xml in which case all the coupling can disappear, but I am not sure whether it is good practice to place resources in a java class and not in res/.

Comment: One of the advantages of using res/strings.xml is that you can do painless i18n - see here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: Can you give an example how introducing a new class would reduce coupling? How would that class be different from the XML file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you're in the market for quick'n'dirty solution, why not hold your array names in another array, and look them up at runtime?

```
<string-array name="array1">
    ...
</string-array>

<string-array name="array2>
    ...
</string-array>

<string-array name="arrays">
    <item>array1</item>
    <item>array2</item>
</string-array>
```

You can then find out how many arrays you currently got by going with the length of your array names array, and look up the required array resource id via

```
getResources().getIdentifier()
```

Not exactly a clean solution, but you'll just need to maintain the string resources. Saves you from changing your code when adding/removing/renaming an array, but you'll still need to touch it in case you decide to rename your naming array.